# HAVING COUNT() not giving out the expected result

Tags: sql, oracle, count, having-clause

Attempting to get duplicate values of produce.prod_id using distinct, having clauses.but not giving out the expected result.

Here's my data:

```
PRODUCE
--------- -----------
 PROD_ID   PROD_NAME
--------- -----------
  1         APPLES
  2         PEARS
  3         ORANGES
  4         BANANAS
  5         PEACHES


BUYERS
---------- ------------
 BUYER_ID   BUYER_NAME
---------- --------------
  1         ADAM BARR
  2         SEAN CHAI
  3         EVA CORETS
  4         ERIN O`MELIA


SALES
---------- --------- ------
 BUYER_ID   PROD_ID   QTY
---------- --------- ------
  1          2          15
  1          3           5
  4          1          37
  3          5          11
  4          3        1005
```

and here's my code:

```
select produce.prod_name,
       buyer.BUYER_NAME,
       SALES.PROD_ID
  from produce
 inner join SALES on produce.PROD_ID = SALES.PROD_ID
 inner join buyer on SALES.BUYER_ID = buyer.BUYER_ID
 group by produce.prod_name,
          buyer.BUYER_NAME,
          SALES.PROD_ID
 having count(SALES.PROD_ID) > 1;
```

Expected result:

```
 PROD_Name   Buyer_Name
----------- --------------
 Oranges     ADAM BARR
 Oranges     ERIN O`MELIA
```

Comment: And you expect... what instead?

Comment: "not the expected result" - *what* did you expect and *what* did you get? Please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use analytical function for your requirement

```
WITH PRODUCE(PROD_ID, PROD_NAME) AS (
 SELECT 1, 'APPLES' from dual union all
 select 2, 'PEARS' from dual union all
 select 3, 'ORANGES' from dual union all
 select 4, 'BANANAS' from dual union all
 select 5, 'PEACHES' from dual),
BUYERS (BUYER_ID, BUYER_NAME) as (
 select 1, 'ADAM BARR' from dual union all
 select 2, 'SEAN CHAI' from dual union all
 select 3, 'EVA CORETS' from dual union all
 select 4, 'ERIN O`MELIA' from dual),
SALES(BUYER_ID, PROD_ID, QTY) as (
 select 1, 2, 15 from dual union all
 select 1, 3, 5 from dual union all
 select 4, 1, 37 from dual union all
 select 3, 5, 11 from dual union all
 select 4, 3, 1005 from dual),
-- End of data preparation
TABLE_ AS (
  SELECT produce.prod_name,
         buyers.buyer_name,
         sales.prod_id,
         COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY sales.prod_id) p_count
    FROM produce
   INNER JOIN sales
      ON produce.prod_id = sales.prod_id
   INNER JOIN buyers
      ON sales.buyer_id = buyers.buyer_id)
SELECT prod_name, buyer_name, prod_id
  FROM table_ 
 WHERE p_count > 1;
```

Output:

```
| PROD_NAME |   BUYER_NAME | PROD_ID |
|-----------|--------------|---------|
|   ORANGES | ERIN O`MELIA |       3 |
|   ORANGES |    ADAM BARR |       3 |
```

Update: You simplified query would be:

```
With TABLE_ AS (
  SELECT produce.prod_name,
         buyers.buyer_name,
         sales.prod_id,
         COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY sales.prod_id) p_count
    FROM produce
   INNER JOIN sales
      ON produce.prod_id = sales.prod_id
   INNER JOIN buyers
      ON sales.buyer_id = buyers.buyer_id)
SELECT prod_name, buyer_name, prod_id
  FROM table_ 
 WHERE p_count > 1;
```

Comment: Darn, you type quicker than me @San.  :-)  

user3979310: The problem is that you're grouping by Buyer as well as ProdID, so the count for  *ADAM BARR, Oranges* will be one unless he bought oranges twice. You need to group one by prodid then join back to get the actual values.

Comment: @San this looks a bit complicated. Any simpler way of doing this would be very much appreciated!

Comment: @user3979310 analytical function count is itself very simplified. I just used your query in CTE with count analytical  function and added a filter later on `where p_count > 1`. I have modified the answer to look simpler. Checkout [this](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions.php) to know more on analytical functions.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need distinct. you only need group by and having. you also cant group by buyer_name to get a count > 1. that is where the issue lies, you can to do this as a set of nested queries

```
select dupes.prod_name, 
buyers.buyer_name 
from (

    select produce.prod_name,
        SALES.PROD_ID,
        count(SALES.PROD_ID)
    from produce 
    inner join SALES on produce.PROD_ID=SALES.PROD_ID
    group by produce.prod_name, 
        SALES.PROD_ID
    having count(*)>1 
) as dupes
inner join sales on sales.prod_id = dupes.prod_id
inner join buyers on buyers.buyer_id = sales.buyer_id
```

Comment: negative!! i'm still getting the output no rows selected

Answer (score 0):

Here's my, hopefully, simple answer.

Here's my SQL Fiddle scratch pad as well. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d80f6/3

```
select P.Prod_Name, Buyer_Name
from Sales S
join
   (select prod_id, count(prod_id) as ActSales
   from Sales group by prod_id having count(prod_id) > 1) SQ
on S.Prod_Id = SQ.Prod_Id
join Produce P
on S.Prod_Id = P.Prod_Id
join Buyers B
on S.Buyer_Id = B.Buyer_Id
```